# How to update Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools from powershell with vs_installer.exe

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2017, build-tools

I want to update the **Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools** on all our build nodes with Powershell and I'm looking for a command that could update them remotely.

There is no **vs_buildtools.exe** anymore but I guess it should also work with **vs_installer.exe**.

It is not enough to type:

> ."c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" update

so I added *--installPath "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\"* but that does not work.

Anyone understands the reference at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio ?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to use vs_installer.exe you have to use `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" -update`

If you want to do it silently you have to `--quiet` or `--passive`

But I dont know if this updates Build Tools to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end after a year I found a good guide that really works

https://alastaircrabtree.com/keeping-visual-studio-2017-build-tools-up-to-date/

and the component list that is needed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you saw that there was no BuildTools anymore.
I see it just fine here: https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe

You can use the following example for installing in command-line:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container#step-5-create-and-build-the-dockerfile

Here is the relevant excerpt:

```
C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache --installPath C:\BuildTools --all \
--remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 \
--remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 \
--remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 \
--remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK \
```

Hope this helps!